# OpenMP only creating a single thread - C

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to make a matrix multiplier using OpenMP to partition the matrix, but when I try and create my threads, only a single thread is being created.

The code is

```
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(P)
        {
                printf("P: %d, Number Threads: %d, Thread Number: %d\n", P, omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_thread_num());
        }
```

I have also tried using `omp_set_num_threads(P)` both inside and outside the pragma. No matter what I do, the only output I get is:
`P: 3, Number Threads: 1, Thread Number: 0`

The variable P is being passed into the function that contains the pragma.
I am also compiling using the -fopenmp flag.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I was using a makefile for compiling my program and had -fopenmp down as a linker flag and not a compilation flag.